# Calculate duration of two dates, first one is utc date, second is browser's local gmt time (London timezone)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have an issue with the calculation of duration between two dates, one is UTC London time, and the second one is the browser's local time.

first date is 2022-04-20T08:29:55.614 (server's UTC time)
second one is 2022-04-20T09:44:16.234 (browser's local time)

I calculate the difference by using the moment:

```
const differenceDate = moment.duration(currentDate.diff(startupDateTime))
```

The difference should be 14 minutes, but the result is 1 hour and 14 minutes.

I tried to use the moment-timezone library but the result was almost the same.

Comment: Can you show how `currentDate` and `startupDateTime` get their values? Chances are that both are being treated as local time.

Comment: @phuzi `const startupDateTime = moment(store.deviceDetails.startupDateTime)
    const currentDate = moment()`

Comment: What is the value of `store.deviceDetails.startupDateTime`? Does it include any timezone info?

Comment: @phuzi `store.deviceDetails.startupDateTime is: 2022-04-20T08:29:55.614`

Comment: I presume that is a string. It does not include any timezone info and is therefore being treated as local time. It would need to besomething like `'2022-04-20T08:29:55.614Z'` or `'2022-04-20T08:29:55.614+00:00'` to be properly treated as UTC/GMT+0